# Updating array in items of template dom-repeat not reflected to dom

Tags: javascript, polymer

Consider this code:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{chats}}" as="item">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <span>{{item.unreadcount}}</span>
</template>
```

I seem to be unable to make sure *replacing* the array (completely, not just updating a property of one of the elements) updates the dom.

Updating I tried like this:

```
var c = this.chats;
c.forEach(function(e) {
    e.unreadcount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}.bind(this));

// none of the following approaches has any effect:
this.chats = c;
this.set("chats", c);
this.notifyPath("chats", c);
```

How can I achieve to re-render the dom if the arrays is changed completely?

**Edit**

Thanks to Maria's hints I figured out how to do it.

It is not enough to use `splice()`, you also need to use Polymer's functions to modify the array itself: `this.set(..., ...)`.

```
for (i = 0; i < this.chats.length; i++) { 
    this.set('chats.'+i+'.unreadcount', Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
this.chats = this.chats.slice();
```

*My forehead starts to flatten due to the massive banging of my head against the wall since starting with Polymer*

Comment: If you do all the manipulations with `this.set`, you shouldn't need `this.chats = this.chats.slice();`. Have tried removing that and checked if it still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that after all these operations, your `chats` property is still the same instance of the array. In any of the approaches you tried, Polymer checks if the instance has changed, it does not check the items in the array for changes. One way to solve this is to create a new copy of the array and assign that to `chats`.

```
this.chats = c.slice();
```

**Update**

While I pretty sure that the above used to work at some point, I can confirm that it does not work anymore. I assume that Polymer has the old values cached somehow. So I think your solution with the `set` API is the best way to go now. I've found that the following works, too, but I'm guessing it is less efficient in most situations. It's resetting the array and then setting the new values asynchronously. In that case, the slice is not even need.

```
this.chats = [];

this.async(function() {
    this.set("chats", c);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is already an improvement :-) If before doing this.chats = slice(c); I add another element to the array (c.push({ ... })), it shows up now in the dom. Changes of properties of the objects in the array however are still not reflected in the dom :-(

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the update. It's a pity just using slice() does not work anymore. Because it now requires some fiddling when I get a new array from my backend, to get the dom know about it :)